# JFileChooser as a JDialog parent

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jfilechooser

In JFileChooser, when trying to overwrite a file, I want my program to prompt the user that he's about to do it.

This is to be done when user pressed APPROVE_OPTION in JFileChooser.

However, I don't want the JFileChooser to close instantly, but if a such file already exist, display a JDialog which would then, if user want's to overwrite, overwrite, otherwise close the JDialog and return to JFileChooser.

I'm aware that I can, before opening the JDialog, save JFileChooser condition and if user chooses not to overwrite just recreate the whole JFileChooser using info I saved.

But I was wondering if there was an easier way. Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to override the approveSelection() method.

```
final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser( new File(".") )
{
    public void approveSelection()
    {
        if (getSelectedFile().exists())
        {
            System.out.println("Do You Want to Overwrite File?");
            return;
        }
        else
            super.approveSelection();
    }
};
```

Instead of displaying the message you can prompt the user with a JOptionPane. If the user accepts then you invoke super.approveSelection();